# ML approach for clustering product descriptions

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I need to cluster different descriptions of parts from catalog data from different vendors. I am trying to find an "approach" that can detect clusters of similar descriptions for purpose of grouping them together.

This is a sample dataset for one part number i.e. 
`A100: ["COCPIT VOICE RECORDER", "RECORDER", "VOICE RECORDER","BELT", "REGULARTOR BELT", "OXIGEN REGULATOR", "BULB", "OXIGEN REG"]`

Expected result of clustering will be i.e. : 
`Cluster 1: ["COCPIT VOICE RECORDER", "RECORDER", "VOICE RECORDER"], 
Cluster 2 : ["BELT"], 
Cluster 3: ["OXIGEN REG", "OXIGEN REGULATOR"], 
Cluster 4: ["BULB"]`

or variations of it.

I never had experience with this but my basic research on ML shows that first thing you need to do is to extract features from data so I tried coming up with some features...

My feature extraction approach was to compare each and every one of these parts with each other using similarity function (i.e. edit distance or Levenstain distance) or Jaro Winkler distance.

Then my idea was to use KMeans algorithm to find clusters? 
Any ideas if this feature selection is good? 
Any other idea about feature extraction or an approach to this problem?
Thanks !

Comment: As a feature, the number of occurrence of each word in the strings (Bag of Words) can be really interesting as it makes no prediction about the relative position of different words.

Comment: I not sure that Bag of Words will be good for this problem, because there are many cases in this data where words are either misspellings or abbreviations. Example: CVR and COCPIT VOICE RECORDER have similarity using "edit distance" but have no common Bag of Words features and I would like them to be in the same cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar where my feature vector is how many times each product description contains each dictionary word (so for each entry you get a long vector which is mostly 0's with a few 1's or 2's). You can then feed this into a clustering alg of your choice (I used kmeans also).

In python the general idea is:

```
# loop over all descriptions to get word list
allWords = {}
for productDesc in products :
    for word in productDesc.split(" ") :
        if(not word in words) :
            words[word] = 0

# build a vector for each description
matrix = []
for productDesc in products :
    vec = words.copy()
    for word in productDesc.split(" ") :
        vec['word'] = vec['word'] + 1

    matrix.append(vec)
```

Once you have a feature matrix like this you can use your favourite clustering algorithm, for this I would use either kmeans directly, or compute a similarity matrix (for each pair of rows in the matrix compute the number of words in common) and then use spectral clustering.